# VPN connection failure

Tags: networking, macos, router, vpn

I recently changed my internet provider and after that I couldn't connect to my work's VPN anymore. I change my router to a TP-Link WR840N but that didn't work. The IPSec pass through is enabled in the router. Before that change everything was working fine.

I'm using OS X El Captain (10.11.6) and the log I get when trying to connect is:

```
Aug  8 21:07:59 my-machine nesessionmanager[1553]: IPSec connecting to server <server - secret>
Aug  8 21:07:59 my-machine nesessionmanager[1553]: IPSec Phase1 starting.
Aug  8 21:07:59 my-machine racoon[2139]: accepted connection on vpn control socket.
Aug  8 21:07:59 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Aug  8 21:07:59 my-machine racoon[2139]: IPSec connecting to server ***.***.***.*
Aug  8 21:07:59 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Aug  8 21:07:59 my-machine racoon[2139]: Connecting.
Aug  8 21:07:59 my-machine racoon[2139]: IPSec Phase 1 started (Initiated by me).
Aug  8 21:07:59 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Aug  8 21:07:59 my-machine racoon[2139]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Aggressive-Mode message 1).
Aug  8 21:07:59 my-machine racoon[2139]: >>>>> phase change status = Phase 1 started by us
Aug  8 21:08:02 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Aug  8 21:08:02 my-machine racoon[2139]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase 1 Retransmit).
Aug  8 21:08:09 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Aug  8 21:08:09 my-machine nesessionmanager[1553]: IPSec Controller: retry IPSec aggressive mode with DH Group 2
Aug  8 21:08:09 my-machine nesessionmanager[1553]: IPSec Phase1 starting.
Aug  8 21:08:09 my-machine racoon[2139]: IPSec connecting to server ***.***.***.*
Aug  8 21:08:09 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Aug  8 21:08:09 my-machine racoon[2139]: Connecting.
Aug  8 21:08:09 my-machine racoon[2139]: IPSec Phase 1 started (Initiated by me).
Aug  8 21:08:09 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Aug  8 21:08:09 my-machine racoon[2139]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Aggressive-Mode message 1).
Aug  8 21:08:09 my-machine racoon[2139]: >>>>> phase change status = Phase 1 started by us
Aug  8 21:08:12 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Aug  8 21:08:12 my-machine racoon[2139]: IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase 1 Retransmit).
Aug  8 21:08:19 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Aug  8 21:08:19 my-machine nesessionmanager[1553]: NESMLegacySession[<secret>]: status changed to disconnecting
Aug  8 21:08:19 my-machine nesessionmanager[1553]: IPSec disconnecting from server ***.***.***.*
Aug  8 21:08:19 my-machine racoon[2139]: IPSec disconnecting from server ***.***.***.*
Aug  8 21:08:19 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Aug  8 21:08:19 my-machine nesessionmanager[1553]: NESMLegacySession[<secret>]: status changed to disconnected, last stop reason None
Aug  8 21:08:19 my-machine racoon[2139]: glob found no matches for path "/var/run/racoon/*.conf"
A
```

Does anybody know what's happening or how to debug this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like your new provider is blocking UDP port 500 outbound and/or inbound.

I.e. your log shows that you are sending message 1 of the IKE AM:

> Aug  8 21:07:59 my-machine racoon[2139]: IKE Packet: transmit success.
>   (Initiator, Aggressive-Mode message 1).

However there is no response, so after some time you re-transmit the first packet:

> Aug  8 21:08:02 my-machine racoon[2139]: IKE Packet: transmit success.
>   (Phase 1 Retransmit).

And as there is still no response, we try again a few times and finally just give up.

So why are we not getting a response?

- Something in the path is blocking the packet
- The VPN head-end is dropping it
- The VPN head-end responds but something in the path drops the response

Given that this used to work ok and only failed after changing ISP, it seems most likely that the ISP is blocking either the outbound or the inbound packets.

I suggest asking the VPN admin at your work if there is another way to connect, e.g. using IPsec over TCP or using TLS.

Comment: You're right!! The ISP was blocking IPsec but now it's working!!